Software Recommendations S.E. doesn't reach its goal: I think that each "research of software" should return to its related S.E
I've experienced Software Recommendations a few times, and also looked at the number of questions inside who received a least an answer, and found that this Stack Exchange isn't really efficient.
There's three problems, I think, that are responsible of that:

Stack Overflow gathers the most experienced users for development tools,
Mathematics S.E. those having knowledge with tools like Sagemath, mathlab or others
etc.

According to Users

Software Recommendations has currently around 74,000 users
Stack Overflow, 25,000,000
Mathematics, 1,150,000
...


Stack Overflow, Mathematics, Linux/Unix S.E. are often browsed by its users for curiosity, and at a time a user finds a question he can reply to, he does.
This doesn't happen with Software Recommendations S.E.: You don't go on it to see what new questions appeared on it these last days, for curiosity.


The result is that, if I consider the effectiveness of a Stack Exchange to reply to a software recommendation question, where do I have the most chances to have an answer if I am in search of a development software, for example?

In a S.E. that has 74,000 users having various knowledge, but many not having development one, and rarely browsing that S.E.,

Or on Stack Overflow, that has 25,000,000 users, specialized in development, and watching it often?


Obviously, it's on Stack Overflow that if the Software Recommendation tag was allowed again (I think it was once), it would be. Respectively, in Mathematics S.E. for Mathematical oriented tools, and so on.
Of course this could mean the risk of finding few same software recommendations if you're considering, for example, Mathematics, Statistics (= crossvalidated S.E.) and Physics S.E. together. Because I guess that few same software can be commonly used by all of them.
I advocate for software recommendation questions going back to their related Stack Exchanges.

Software recommendation questions are often extremely poor and attract various non-answers in many ways. The answers also often become useless as a link rots or a software stops existing, or maybe even it changes its name but the old answer doesn't. There is also the issue of spam - recommendations attract a lot of spam. Finding a recommendation question from few years ago almost inevitably means that a large portion of the answers are useless now, or deleted, or might also have never been correct even when initially posted. Your proposal skips how to deal with any of these real problems.

"on Stack Overflow that if the Software Recommendation tag was allowed again (I think it was once)" back then when a site just started growing, almost everything was asked, and the community evaluated which worked and which didn't. In the end, most communities decided it didn't work (further: Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!). Thus, [SoftwareRecs.SE] (and [HardwareRecs.SE]) is the only alternative SE for those. That doesn't mean that all sites disallow recommendations, only that some decided it didn't worth.

I'm voting to close this question as needing more focus because the final request here, which is that software recommendation questions be once again allowed on all technical sites, is too broad for a request here. Each site makes its own decisions on what types of questions are allowed, and I highly recommend you do some research as to why the sites decided to ban them in the first place. @MetaAndrewT. pointed out some good links.

In fact, as you read those early posts, they all come to the conclusion that the SE engine was never designed for recommendation questions. That's why after Software and Hardware Recommendations launched, they put a stop to future site proposals for recommendations.

@VLAZ I disagree, there isn't that much spam and most solutions remain valid for many years (typically, only very minor or cloud-based programs can disappear).

@FranckDernoncourt On a per question posted in the timeframe for which we have records (start Q3/Q4 2015) basis, the rate of spam posts (true positive in metasmoke) is 8.8 times higher on SW Recs and 4.2 times higher on HW Recs, than it is on SO. So, while there is dramatically less spam on a total volume basis, there's a substantially higher rate of spam posts.

@Makyen thanks, higher rate of spam posts doesn't imply high rate. What's the rate?

@FranckDernoncourt SO: 0.005710588/question; SW Recs: 0.050603693/question; HW Recs: 0.024062279/question. Rates are per currently non-deleted question posted since the first dated report on metasmoke for each site.

@Makyen cool thanks for the stats! 5% of spam is a bit high indeed but 95% of non-spam still sounds reasonably usable, so not a major issue imho.

@FranckDernoncourt Higher rate does imply high rate. There is no empirical way to say "this is a high rate". The only real way to measure it is relative to other rates. It's also how humans are going to experience it, which is what matters, particularly when making a determination as to "should these sets be combined on one site" from the point of view of the people experiencing the influx of posts and spam.

@Makyen if the spam rate was 0.0000001%, nobody would care about it, even if it was higher compared to another site.

@FranckDernoncourt Yes, of course, as with almost anything, you can get agreement on "high"/"low" at the extremes. However, that and the discussion of what is "high"/"low" is nearly useless, because where those are defined are, really, just opinions and will be different across many people. In addition, what people actually experience is completely divorced from the empirical specification of these rates. What people experience is "do I feel the rate of spam is high on site A". If they do, then the relative rate on B or C is what can be used to gauge how they will feel on those sites.

OK, on the rates discussion - also worth noting that when spam is posted on a recommendation question on SO, the question itself is usually closed in a short order, thus limiting the opportunity for more spam in the future. So, most spam posted on a recommendation also does pruning of the options for spam. If no closing was done, there should be even more spam per recommendation post.

@Makyen I don't feel that the rate of spam is high. I barely recall flagging any post as spams. I guess I should use that site more often.  I wish I could see that list of deleted spams. I glanced at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days but out of the 45 recently deleted posts over the past 3 weeks, I saw only 1 spam.

I'm a former Software recommendations and current Super User moderator, so I 'understand' the problem at both ends.
On regular sites - we found that software recommendation questions didn't work for us - and we sort of found a workaround that fit our needs, asking about the process of solving a problem rather than a bare software recommendation.
Even within SR, we needed some very specific recommendations to avoid being just a list of links. It's a particularly hard problem that needs a certain very specific style of curation and answering.
You're kind of looking at it from the 'wrong' angle - there are effective ways to do a pseudo software recommendation already - asking how you would solve a problem and in a sense discoverability of smaller sites isn't great, which would be a better problem to solve.
I'd also wonder/ask how one might encourage cross-network participation instead. Once a site hits some critical mass, it tends to survive, so things like, perhaps some form of awareness of domain-related questions (Ask Ubuntu chat does this neat thing of adding a RSS feed of U&L questions with the ubuntu tag on them - but this needs activity and buy in on chat).
Maybe adding a sidebar entry with a random, un/under answered appropriately tagged question off the other site. Maybe looking again at active site promotion. There are other options that don't shoehorn in software recommendations in their bare form.
I don't really think we'd be happy with software and hardware recommendations shoehorned into our scope at super user and this may be true of other sites as well.

"On the regular sites - we found that software recommendation questions didn't work for us - and we sort of found a workaround that fit our needs, asking about the process of solving a problem rather than a bare software recommendation." That's specific to SU (and "didn't work for us" just means it was decided not to allow software recommendation questions on SU). Some other sites don't require masquerading software recommendation questions, e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-rec, https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation etc.
